# Difficulty understanding indices sequence

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, jupyter

We trying to filter data from a certain input file but I had trouble understanding certain lines in what they were referring to exactly with the indices. (the ones I didn't understand had the #line comment next to it)

Input file :

```
Peter, Haddad, M, Dekweneh, 5100

Petra, Yahya, Haddad, F, Jbeil, 4321

Walid, Khaled, M, Beirut, 1726

Sako, Kazanjian, M, Ain Ebel, 1121

Patrick, Haddad, M, Dekweneh, 5100

Joseph, Yahya, M, Jounieh, 36

Zoulaykha, Haddad, F, Dekweneh, 5100

Marina, Saadeh, Haddad, F, Chwaifet, 1819

Rami, Saad, M, Jbeil, 4321

Bernard, Khaled, M, Beirut, 1726

Charbel, Kazanjian, M, Ain Ebel, 1121

Cynthia, Khaled, F, Beirut, 1726

Najib, Mansour, M, Beirut, 1726
```

```
for line in in_lines:
    first_name = line.strip().split(' , ')[0]
    
    
    if len(line.strip().split(', ')) == 5:
        reg_num = line.strip().split(', ')[4]
        reg_city= line.strip().split(', ')[3]
        last_name = line.strip().split(', ')[1]
        m_name= ''
        if line.strip().split(', ')[2] == 'F':
            err_file.write(line)
            
    elif len(line.strip().split(', ')) == 6:
        reg_num = line.strip().split(', ')[5]
        reg_city= line.strip().split(', ')[4]
        last_name = line.strip().split(', ')[1]
        m_name= line.strip().split(', ')[2]
        
    if reg_num not in dict_fam:
        dict_fam[reg_num] = [[first_name, last_name, m_name, reg_city]]
    else:
        if last_name == dict_fam[reg_num][0][1]: #Line 1
            dict_fam[reg_num].append([first_name,last_name,m_name,reg_city])
            
        else:
             err_file.write(line)
                
items = dict_fam.items()

for item in items:
    out_file.write(item[1][0][1] + ': ') #Line 2
    for i in item[1]:
        out_file.write(i[0] + ', ') #Line 3
         
        
    out_file.write('\n')
    
print(dict_fam)

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
err_file.close()
```

I mainly didn't understand what the purpose of these lines were.

Comment: That's quite a bit of parsing code. Have you considered using `pd.read_csv()` or the `csv` module?

Comment: Might be an idea if you explain **exactly** what you're trying to extract from the input file and what you want to do with it. Also, does your input file have empty lines or is that just how you've formatted the data in your question?

Comment: First of all please consider creating a list for once at the beggining instead of calling `line.strip().split(', ')` everytime.

Anyways:
Line1 : it seems that dict_fam is a directory with the information of a family, and if the last name of the line correspond to last_time of the given `reg_num` then it adds the information of the family member.

Line 2 and 3, it writes some of the information contained in dict_fam in a text file open under the `out_file` name. however without knowing how dict_fam is encoded I can't answer further.

Comment: Now I see your confusion. The variable *item* is a tuple comprised of a dictionary key and its associated value. Thus *item[1]* is the value